# MATLAB & Mex-Files: Auto-optimization of CUDA-Code depending on Input-Parameters size

Tags: optimization, matlab, cuda, mex

Hey there,
I'm currently developing a Mex-file in matlab including CUDA computation. I wonder if there's a good way to 'automatically' optimize the program for arbitrary input parameters from the user. E.g. when the input-parameters don't exceed a certain size, try to use shared and/or constant memory... which will only work up to certain limits. From there on, global memory has to be used. But such optimizations can only be made in runtime because that's the point I get to know the size of input parameters from the user. Any simple solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write different kernels and decide which ones to call at runtime.

You can also use the device query API or do some micro-benchmarking to figure out the sizes of shared/constant memory at runtime. This is probably necessary if you don't want to assume a particular GPU model.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, that sounds good. So when I have a global variable which is `__constant__` this doesn't make my program slower when I don't do anything with it (e.g. when calling the kernel for a bigger problem size so that the constant memory is too small)? Is the constant and shared memory different per GPU model?

Comment: That question is quite different from the original one. Please either edit your original question or post a new question. Answering it correctly will take some space.